# How to write code to loop lookups over sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I know what I want to do and the logic seems fairly easy. However, when it comes down to actually writing the code for it, it seems quite complicated for someone my level.

I have an Excel workbook with 2 Sheets.

**Sheet 1** contains, 200 First and Last Names in Columns A & B and 13 Dates in Row 1. The rest of the spread Sheet is empty.
**Sheet 2** contains the results of a doodle for eleven 1 hour blocks (09:00 - 20:00) on those dates for the same 200 people from Sheet 1. So Sheet 2 contains the same names in Columns A & B, Dates in Row 1 where the dates are repeated 11 times in consecutive cells to accommodate the eleven 1 hour blocks which are in Row 2, followed by the rest of the spreadsheet filled with one of the three values - "Yes", "No" and "Maybe", for each of the 1 hour blocks that were available per date for each name.

I want to fill each cell in Sheet 1 the times at which each person in Sheet 1 marked themselves as "Yes" in Sheet 2. So, If Person 1 marked themselves "Yes" on Hours 09:00 - 10:00, 11:00-12:00 and 13:00-14:00 on Sheet 2 for the 31/03/2020, I would like to concatenate these hour blocks exactly as follows 
09:00-10:00
11:00-12:00
13:00-14:00
and then input this into the corresponding cell for that name and date on Sheet 1.

I must confess that I only just started looking at coding for VBA Excel about 5 hours ago. So I actually have no code I can present. I have been trying to use loops, arrays, tables, lookups and so on. And I have been running into issues with the fact that my sheets have different data types.

Comment: Welcome to the community! I'm having a little trouble visualizing what your two worksheets look like; can you maybe post a screenshot of each of them? Basically it sounds like you'll want to iterate through each name on Sheet 1 (`For x = 1 to lastRow1`) and then probably inside of that loop iterate through each row on Sheet 2 (`For y = 1 to lastRow2`). If the name found in row y is the same as in row x, add to a string (`str = str & " " & Sheet2.Cells(y,3)`), then at the end write that string to the corresponding row in Sheet 1 (`Sheet1.Cells(x,3) = str`).

Comment: Hello @barvobot!

Comment: Hey @barvobot!
I believe I am not allowed to post pictures since I have less than 10 rep. In any case, I am almost sure that you got the logic right. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to @CDP1802 for doing the whole thing. I just edited a few small things! Thanks alot!

```
    Sub mysub()

        Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, c2 As Integer, s As String, d As Integer

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

        ' scan sheet 2
        For r = 3 To 202 ' or whatever the last row is
            For d = 0 To 12 ' 13 dates
                s = ""
                ' work out first columns on sheet2 for that d
                c2 = 3 + d * 11
                For c = c2 To (c2 + 10)
                    If ws2.Cells(r, c) = "Yes" Then
'                   Pick up time from row 2 in Sheet 2
                        s = s & ws2.Cells(2, c) & vbNewLine 
                    End If
                    If ws2.Cells(r, c) = "Under reserve" Then
'                   Pick up time from row 2 in Sheet 2 and place it in parenthesis
                        s = s & "(" & ws2.Cells(2, c) & ")" & vbNewLine
                        End If
                Next
' Insert the resulting string of times in Sheet 1. Sheet 1 has one less rows, hence r-1
                ws1.Cells(r - 1, d + 3) = s
            Next
        Next
        MsgBox "Done"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Principle would be to scan down and across sheet1 using some basic mathematics to
determine the range of cells on sheet 2 to be examined for "Yes"

```vb
Sub mysub()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, c2 As Integer, s As String, d As Integer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    ' scan sheet 1
    For r = 3 To 10 ' or whatever the last row is
        For d = 0 To 10 ' 11 dates
            s = ""
            ' work out first columns on sheet2 for that d
            c2 = 3 + d * 11
            For c = c2 To (c2 + 10)
                If ws2.Cells(r, c) = "Yes" Then
                    s = s & ws2.Cells(2, c) & " " ' row 2 for time
                End If
            Next
            ws1.Cells(r, d + 3) = s
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think you misunderstood my question. There are 13 dates. Each date is divided into 11 one hour blocks. This means that the loop will run once for each name on Sheet 1 and 11 times for each of the 13 dates in Sheet 2 so as to identify the "Yes" answers per date and finally, returning a concatenated text consisting of the hour blocks  that have a yes for each specific date.

Comment: @noob Sheet 1 has 201 rows and 15 columns (2 name, 13 dates), sheet 2 has 201 rows, 145 columns = 13 * 11 + 2 for name. On sheet 2 each of the time/date cells has Yes,No or maybe. That's what I thought you meant.

Comment: Hey! You're right there! That is exactly what I meant! Gonna run the code again. :)  Just that I saw something about 11 dates in the comments on the code and that confused me.

Comment: @noob you are right, it should be For d = 0 To 12 ' 13 dates

Comment: Thanks a lot though. I was able to use it nonetheless. I am actually kinda proud of myself for having understood that part and fixed it. :)

Now All I need to do is figure out how to have an extra If loop for the "Maybe" responses and make changes in the format of the output.:D Do you think you can help me with that too?

Comment: The maybe's should also get picked up the same way as the Yes, however these would be input into the cell inside parenthesis. Kinda like this
09:00-10:00
(10:00-11:00)
11:00-12:00
where 10:00-11:00 had a maybe and the other two hours had a Yes.

Comment: Hey! Guess what! :D I managed to do it myself! :P
So proud of myself now! :P

Just one question though. My result is always shifted by one row. So Sheet1 always has the resulted shifted one row lower than it should. Any clue why? I've been messing with the row numbers but not able to figure it out.

Comment: Managed that too!

Thanks a lot @CDP1802. You got the ball rolling for me! :)

I guess the reason I was stuck was because I was trying to treat VBA like Exccel functions. Will post the solution here.